# Extract BRIEF features with mexopencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, mex, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract binary features in Matlab with mexopencv. If I use ORB as a detector and extractor everything works fine. The problem is when I try to use BRIEF extractor. This is the code I am using:

```
detector = cv.FeatureDetector('ORB');
extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('BRIEF'); % if I use 'ORB' here everything works fine

img = read('my-image');
keyPoints = detector.detect(img);
descriptors = extractor.compute(img, keyPoints);
```

And I get the following error:

> Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'cv.DescriptorExtractor' class destructor:
>   MxArray is not a scalar
>
> In extract_train_orb (line 5) 
>   Error using DescriptorExtractor_
>   Unrecognized extractor BRIEF
>
> Error in cv.DescriptorExtractor (line 63)
>               this.id = DescriptorExtractor_(0, 'new', extractorType, varargin{:});
>
> Error in extract_train_orb (line 2)
>   extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('BRIEF');

I do not know how to solve this issue, as the [mexopencv's documentation](https://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/matlab/DescriptorExtractor.DescriptorExtractor.html) says BRIEF is a supported extractor.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks

**EDIT:**

In fact, ORB is the only type currently working. 'BRIEF', 'SURF' and 'SIFT' types are getting the same error.

I am using OpenCV 3.0 and Matlab R2015b under Ubuntu 14.04.

**EDIT 2:**

`contrib module` was not installed. 
I download [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/), re-build & re-install OpenCV and finally, try to compile mexopencv contrib module by:

```
make MATLABDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b contrib
```

Compilation fails with this error:

> /tmp/mex_619067277620954_21116/BriefDescriptorExtractor_.o: In function ``mexFunction':
>   BriefDescriptorExtractor_.cpp:(.text+0x31d8): undefined reference to `createBriefDescriptorExtractor(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Could you try with type `'BriefDescriptorExtractor'`? You also probably need `xfeatures2d` from contrib module if you're using OpenCV 3.0

Comment: Thanks @Miki but type 'BriefDescriptorExtractor' is not working either.

Comment: Have a look at line 672 [here](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/src/mexopencv_features2d.cpp). It should work as I mentioned... can you double check?

Comment: @Miki I think the problem is in the contrib module, as you said. I have realized it was not installed, so I download OpenCV's code, re-build & re-install OpenCV and finally, try to compile mexopencv contrib module. But compilation of the contrib module crashes anyway.

Comment: Finally, I solve it by rebuilding OpenCV with contrib module and clean and rebuild mexopencv. Also, I have to write type as 'BriefDescriptorExtractor', as 'BRIEF' does not work. So, if you put this in a answer, I will accept it @Miki

Comment: I  can't right now. Feel free to post and accept your own answer. Glad you make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to @Miki suggestions.

1. First, the contrib module should be installed. I re-installed OpenCV 3.0 as in [this guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/). Then, I run `make clean`, `make` and `make contrib` on mexopencv directory.
2. Finally, I had to use

   `extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('BriefDescriptorExtractor');`

   instead of

   `extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('BRIEF');`

Answer (score 1):

It might be about incompatibilities between feature detectors and descriptor extractors. For example can you try using 'SURF' for both detector and extractor?

Even if my suggestion works, I would have expect 'ORB' detector to work with 'BRIEF' extractor, since 'ORB' is just 'Oriented BRIEF'. However you should be sure about the compatibilities of detectors and feature extractors, maybe you should read papers about these techniques. For instance some extractors also produces scale or octave in addition to keypoints, and some doesn't. Similarly some descriptors expect to have scale or octave input with keypoints, and some doesn't.

Here is a primitive example; you can't charge an iPhone with Samsung charger or visa versa. Both are phones both have chargers, but they do not match.

Comment: Thanks @guneykayim but incompatibility between detectors/extractors is not the problem. SURF and SIFT are not working in any case (`cv.FeatureDetector('SURF')` produces a similar error) and BRIEF should definitely work with ORB.

Comment: @user1805638 Did you add `xfeatures2d` as @Miki suggested?